# how to select part.surface in abaqus using python script

Tags: python, abaqus

How do I select the surfaces on part in Abaqus? I have tried:

```
tubePart.surface(faces = tubePart.faces[4:8],name = 'innerFaces')
```

but it keeps saying part object has no attribute surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should create a new surface by calling `Surface()` function (not `surface()`), i.e.

```
tubePart.Surface(...)
```

Secondly, there must be `side1Faces` instead of `faces` (thanks to agentp for comment). Thus, the final peace of code should look like this:

```
tubePart.Surface(side1Faces = tubePart.faces[4:8],name = 'innerFaces')
```